# Filtering Results of a CTE to eventually end up in a SQL report

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, common-table-expression

I am working with SSMS, SQL Server, and SSRS.  I have results in a CTE that I want to filter further 'after' it is run.

The query looks for multiple entries of ID's in a table. Then it selects the ones that have null values.  This is a correct selection and I need to narrow the scope down further.

At this point I would in the past dump the output of this into an excel file and look for and highlight duplicate values in the ID field and only show those rows. My goal is to get this into a SSRS report.

Do I just need to create a view then run another CTE view against it, some type of nested query, or store a procedure and filter out the results or use a user defined function?  Can I use something like a comma after the first CTE and maybe do another WITH statement?  Thanks in advance.

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT [ID] ,
    [LOCATION] ,
    [LOCATION_START_DATE],
    [LOCATION_END_DATE],
    [POS],
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID]) as Cnt
FROM LOCATIONS_TABLE WITH (NOLOCK)
)
SELECT  [ID] ,
    [LOCATION] ,
    [LOCATION_START_DATE],
    [LOCATION_END_DATE],
    [POS]
FROM T
WHERE Cnt >= 2
AND LOCATION_END_DATE IS NULL
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Your question would become a lot clearer with sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cascade several CTEs as follows:

```
WITH 
    T AS (
        SELECT [ID] ,
            [LOCATION] ,
            [LOCATION_START_DATE],
            [LOCATION_END_DATE],
            [POS],
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID]) as Cnt
        FROM LOCATIONS_TABLE WITH (NOLOCK)
    ),
    U AS (
        SELECT  [ID] ,
            [LOCATION] ,
            [LOCATION_START_DATE],
            [LOCATION_END_DATE],
            [POS]
        FROM T
        WHERE Cnt >= 2
        AND LOCATION_END_DATE IS NULL
    )
SELECT ...
```

Comment: You can even join back to a previously cascaded cte (if you need to for some reason)

Comment: Thanks.  This worked out perfectly after I corrected some of my syntax.  Appreciate It.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local **#temporary_table**, insert the CTE results into this **#temporary_table** and filter the results as a selection, saving it to a file as you wish.

The advantage of this approach is that **#temporary_tables** are much faster than nested queries and normal tables. Another advantage is that you can create other queries that make other filters in the #temporary_table, which are less complex than the nested CTE and allow you to generate other reports without modifying the CTE whenever you need a new filter.

You can create a local temporary table in the same way as creating a normal table.

```
CREATE TABLE #temporary_table_name(
-- fields that match the results of the CTE
);
```

You can insert records to a temporary table in the same way as you would in a normal table.

```
INSERT INTO #temporary_table_name.
```

The disadvantage is that the temporary tables are deleted with the stored data every time the user who created them ends the connection.

I hope it helped you!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will keep the temp tables in may toolkit for later on.  Appreciate the assistance.